# Want to add additional function (of determining number of paragraphs in an article) to ad inserting plugin

Tags: php

I'm using a site specific plugin to insert ads between paragraphs of my blog post. The plugin works smooth. It's code is like this-

```
<?php
//Insert ads after second paragraph of single post content.
add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_insert_post_ads' );
function prefix_insert_post_ads( $content ) {
$ad_code = '<div>Ads code goes here</div>';
if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 2, $content );
}
return $content;
}
// Parent Function that makes the magic happen
function prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content) 
{    
$closing_p = '</p>';
$paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {
if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
$paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
}
if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
$paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
}
}
return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}`
```

It works well and displays ad code wherever it is asked to.

I want to add another function into it. I want the plugin to determine the number of paragraphs available in a post and display ad only if the post has a minimum number of paragraphs (say 10).

In short, the plugin must display ad only if there are at least 10 paragraphs in the article. If a post is shorter than that, the ad shouldn't be shown by the plugin.

Can anyone help me out with this task?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You could count the number of closing `p` tags via regex if that's how you define a "paragraph"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) is responsible for this kind of thing:

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$paragraphs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
echo $paragraphs->length; // Outputs number of <p> elements
```

Within your function:

```
function prefix_insert_post_ads($content)
{
    $ad_code = '<div>Ads code goes here</div>';
    $dom = new \DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($content);
    $paragraphs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
    if (is_single() && !is_admin() && $paragraphs->length > 10 /*more than ten paragraphs*/) {
        return prefix_insert_after_paragraph($ad_code, 2, $content);
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Hi @revo, the code works fine! Thanks for the help. BTW, the '\' before DOMDocument, I removed it. Is it necessary to have it in the code?

Comment: @ArunKallarackal It's a good practice to include backslash. However its need is more obvious when you are going with an OOP approach (it will bring you to the global namespace). If my answer was helpful please mark it as accepted.